# Force to using NavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

I'm new to iOS. I've read lot of tutorial and I see that all most of example using NavigationController in multiple view. We always force to use NavigationController?

If I have a single view, on my view I have a button1, and when I click on that button it's will open a new view. I also have another button2, when I click on button2, a dialog display on original view. So in this case, I still have to use NavigationController? Another controller I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation controller is not an only option... If u made the flow of your app in such a way that it requires navigation,then only u should use navigation controller.. otherwise there is an another option like presentModalViewController,and u can also use hide/show view while showing dialog in your original view. If you can elaborate your question ,then i might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly for aesthetic reasons and continuity of user experience that you use navigation controller. You of course can use buttons, but navigation controller is more like the standard for multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use the Navigation controller..You can give similar kind of side transition(LEFT to Right or right to left) using Quartz-core animation effect.

```
Home *homeObject=[[Home alloc] init];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[self presentModalViewController:homeObject animated:NO];
[animation setDuration:0.40];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[[homeObject.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
[homeObject release];
```